# EXE shows exception when run in mandarin language machines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winform EXE running using .NET 2.0 framework, when i sent this EXE to my friend who is using a machine where ALL the settings/OS(windows) are displayed in mandarin language.

When i try to open the EXE, i straight away get exceptions in mandarin language.

Is there something i need to change if i need to run an winforms .net EXE in mandarin machines?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible he does not have the .NET framework 2 or later installed and that the error is reporting this?

Comment: *You* get an exception when *he* opens it?  Hmm.  Ask him to translate the message.

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be a whole host of localization issues. My own software has only been used with European scripts, but I still have to handle different number and date formats. So even simple things like reading and writing numbers from the registry (for default settings) require localization support. .NET 2 provides localization support - use the CultureInfo class to determine which formatting method/etc is causing the problem.

You will also need to do everything in Unicode (which you probably already know).

Running your program in a debugger should give insights as to what exactly is failing.

Comment: A MissingManifestResourceException is thrown when the attempt to retrieve a resource fails because the resource set for the neutral culture could not be loaded from a particular assembly, may be neutral/default will be english & that machine's OS might be in mandarin, how to identify the current culture language from .NET & make it to select mandarin's resource file.

Comment: It is worth a look on MSDN, eg.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb6a8618(v=VS.80).aspx. I see Appress also have a book. MSDN's Bing kept trying to give me ASP.NET refs rather than windows applications, but The MSDN pages include some blog links which will be worth reading.